# Swift - best way to animate buttons in tactile, fluid way? Swipe down for menu buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

Alright, Im pretty new to animations in Swift and will be implementing a swipe down for 3 circular menu buttons to "pop" up (move up from button) as my menu.

I will be doing other animations and need this to be as fluid/tactile as possible - I dont just want the buttons to move up (I know how to do this), I want them to come up then move down a little to look extremely clean and fluid - almost like bouncing or "floating". Bobbing is probably the better word here.

I've included a picture below of what Im going for essentially - just trying to find the right way to get into this;

How can I achieve an extremely fluid "bobbing" animation for my menu buttons? In general how I can create tactile/really fluid (not just simple moving) animations in Swift? What are the best tutorials for this?[image]

This is what I mean by fluid -https://dribbble.com/shots/1368542-Gif-Fiche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function all the time for any fluid transition I need.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 
        0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {

    //above change the duration to the time it will take, 
    //and fiddle with the springs between 0-1 until you are happy with the effect.

    //chnage frame however you want to here

    }, completion: { finished in
    //code that runs after the transition is complete here                  
})
```